# Extracting from an array of strings, strings that contain a substring in them (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, string

A question in Python (3.9.5) and Pandas:

Suppose I have an array of strings `x` and I want to extract all the elements that contains a certain substring, e.g. `feb05`. Is there a Pythonic way to do it in one-line, including using a Pandas functions?

Example for what I mean:

```
x = ["2023_jan05", "2023_jan_27", "2023_feb04", "2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"]
must_contain = "feb05"
desired_output = ["2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"]
```

I can run a loop,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

desired_output = []
indices_bool = np.zeros(len(x))
for idx, test in enumerate(x):
   if must_contain in test:
      desired_output.append(test)
      indices_bool[idx] = 1
```

but I seek for a more Pythonic way to do it.

In my application `x` is a column in a Pandas dataframe, so answers with Pandas functions will also be welcomed. The goal is to filter all the rows that has `must_contain` in the field `x` (e.g. `x = df["names"]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are with pandas, you can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to get the boolean condition:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["2023_jan05", "2023_jan_27", "2023_feb04", "2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"]})
must_contain = "feb05"

df.x.str.contains(must_contain)
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#4     True
#Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Filter by the condition:

```
df[df.x.str.contains(must_contain)]
#            x
#3  2023_feb05
#4  2024_feb05
```

Answer (score 1):

no pandas

```
list(filter(lambda y: must_contain in y,x))

["2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"]
```

pandas

```
series=pd.Series(["2023_jan05", "2023_jan_27", "2023_feb04", "2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"])
must_contain = "feb05"
series[series.str.contains(must_contain)].to_list()

["2023_feb05", "2024_feb05"]
```